# render xhtml file from servlet

Tags: java, jsf, servlets, xhtml

I wonder if there is a way to load, interpret and render a .xhtml file from a servlet.
What I want is to have a xhtml file witch contain for example a custom row within a list, to be loaded from a servlet or a bean, to be interpreted, and to obtain the html result.

Comment: Why would you need that?

Comment: I just want to keep separate java code from xhtml / html / css code.

Comment: You will do if you put your Java code on the Managed Beans only. What's your real problem?

Comment: I am new to java and jsf (coming from php).

Comment: If you explain what you really want to do, I'm sure we can put you on a better and simplier way to do it!

Comment: If that's the case, welcome to the JSF world! You can start reading about JSF in [our wiki page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info) and the tutorials inside it (look for JSF 2), specially mkyong and BalusC (JSF expert).

Comment: ok, I want to make rewrite the site at: http://anunturi.orasultau.ro/. The center of page have a list with various announces. every row is defined in a template with html code.

Comment: You can do that using a `@ViewScoped` managed beand that contains a `List<Product>`. You first need to learn the basics of JSF and come with a concrete problem, otherwise it's like you're asking us to do the work for you.

Comment: The concrete problem is the one in question: I wonder if there is a way to load, interpret and render a .xhtml file from a servlet. What I want is to have a xhtml file witch contain for example a custom row within a list, to be loaded from a servlet or a bean, to be interpreted, and to obtain the html result.

Comment: I manged to do this in asp, but now I want to make this in jsf. It can be done, or not?

Comment: You're going in the wrong direction when attempting to solve this by a plain vanilla servlet. Stop concentrating on converting an existing site. First concentrate on learning JSF2 by a sane book/tutorial/resource and playing/sandboxing/experimenting with it for some time. Then apply the lessons learnt on converting the old site.

Comment: I wonder what you wound up doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds to me like you're not in need of Servlets or JSF, but rather JSP (should look familiar, coming from PHP).

Notice that people here will tumble over themselves telling you to not put the logic into the page (and for good reason), but I think with your background, you'll be helped by *starting* from a JSP only approach. Than start moving the logic to a servlet. You can use a number of techniques to communicate the data between the servlet and the jsp. I like to use

```
request.setAttribute("someString", valueObject);
```

In your jsp you than can use:

```
<%= request.getAttribute("someString") %>
```

Calling your jsp from the servlet is done via

```
RequestDispatcher rd = req.getRequestDispatcher("/path.to.your.jsp");
```

If you really need a .xhtml file (your original question), you can use this last line as well, but it'll be real xhtml, like it would be served from a plain webserver (!= appserver)

Comment: *"I just want to keep separate java code from xhtml / html / css code."* This answer does exactly the opposite (apart from not answering OP's concrete question at all).